# How to overcome the asynchronous useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, react-hooks

The asynchronous nature of `useState` is preventing a state from arriving in time for my function.

```js
   const [pushToken, setPushToken] = useState('')
   const storeToken = async () => {
        const token = await registerForToken()

        if (token) {
            try {
                await AsyncStorage.setItem(NOTIFICATION_TOKEN, token)
                setPushToken(token)
            } catch (err) {
                throw new Error(err)
            }
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (borrowerPending) {
            storeToken()
        }

        try {
            someMutation({
                variables: {
                    someParameter: pushToken // this pushToken is still empty
                }
            })
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error(err)
        }
    }, [borrowerPending])
```

The `setPushToken(token)` only renders the `pushToken` on the second render.  How do I set up so that it shows up on the first run?

I tried using `AsyncStorage.getItem(NOTIFICATION_TOKEN)` instead of the `setPushToken` hook, but still the same result

**Update**

```js
   const [pushToken, setPushToken] = useState('')
   const storeToken = async () => {
        const token = await registerForPushNotificationsAsync()

        if (token) {
            try {
                await AsyncStorage.setItem(NOTIFICATION_TOKEN, token)
                setPushToken(token)
            } catch (err) {
                throw new Error(err)
            }
        } else {
         // do something else
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (borrowerPending) {
            storeToken().then(() => {
                console.log("pushToken", pushToken)
                try {
                    borrowerPendingToggle({
                        variables: {
                            borrowerPendingNotificationToken: pushToken
                        }
                    })
                } catch (err) {
                    throw new Error(err)
                }
            })
        }
    }, [borrowerPending])
```

Comment: Hard to tell without full context, but your best bet might be to do the async action in the parent component and only render this component after the async action completes

Comment: When the `useEffect` runs `storeToken()` runs. And by doing so, the `setPushToken` hook is run. But, `pushToken` inside `useEffect` is still empty

Comment: What I'm saying is you won't get away from the `useEffect` hook running simultaneously with the initial component render, which is why I suggest you lift the async action up to a parent component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the sending of the mutation in a separate`useEffect` than the setting of the token:

```
const [pushToken, setPushToken] = useState("");

const storeToken = async () => {
  const token = await registerForToken();

  if (token) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(NOTIFICATION_TOKEN, token);
      setPushToken(token);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
};

// Store the token
useEffect(() => {
  if (borrowerPending) {
    storeToken();
  }
}, [borrowerPending, storeToken]); // You should reference all dependencies in the array, not just borrowerPending.

// This runs when the value of pushToken changes, so will run once the token has been stored.
useEffect(() => {
  if (pushToken) {
    try {
      someMutation({
        variables: {
          someParameter: pushToken
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  }
}, [pushToken, someMutation]);
```